# Which Java XML RPC library to use

Tags: java, xml, xml-rpc, rpc

There seems to be two options for using [xml-rpc](/questions/tagged/xml-rpc) in normal [java](/questions/tagged/java):

- [javax.xml.rpc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/rpc/package-summary.html) - seems more complicated but is a part of standard jdk (or is it?)
- [org.apache.xmlrpc](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/apidocs/org/apache/xmlrpc/package-summary.html) - seems more easy to use, but i have to attach the library in my jar (or do i?)

Which one should I use for a dektop Java app? Or maybe there is another one that is really good and I have no idea it exists?

Comment: JAX-RPC was replaced by by JAX-WS back in Java EE 5.

Comment: @BenTaliadoros: Unfortunately not, as its communicating with a non-jvm  system.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan: How does JAX-WS compare to Apache's XMLRPC ?

Comment: I recommend sticking with standards based solution unless the alternative provides enough value to go the proprietary path.  The latest Apache XMLRPC binaries haven't been updated since 2010 so it may no longer be under active development.

Comment: Maybe development has halted, but it works. The development stopped because there is simply little to add, its stable.

Comment: It's an old question but a critical vulnerability has been found in the apache library. It is not maintained so the vuln won't be fixed: https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-17570

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up going with `org.apache.xmlrpc`, predominantly because my server does not send a WSDL file at all. This is not to say it would be impossible with JAX-WS. I am actually quite certain that JAX-WS is a more robust solution with many more features than Apache XMLRPC. However, the simple fact of the matter is I spent about 4 hours trying to implement user login to Drupal through JAX-WS with no results, after which I turned to Apache XMLRPC and had a working case in 10 minutes.