# Java <-> Python: share objects

Tags: java, python, connection, shared

I have an embedded system using a python interface. Currently the system is using a (system-local) XML-file to persist data in case the system gets turned off. But normally the system is running the entire time. When the system starts, the XML-file is read in and information is stored in python-objects. The information then is used for processing. My aim is to edit this information remotely (over TCP/IP) even during process. I would like to use JAVA to get this done, and i have been thinking about something to share the objects. The problem is, that I'm missing some keywords to find the right technologies to get this done. What i found is SOAP, but i think it is not the right thing for this case, is that true? I'm grateful for any tips.

Comment: You can have a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068052/passing-data-between-java-and-python

It should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you are using XML file to store start up configuration

And my assumptions on your interface between Java & Python  apps

- You want your Java application to retrieve objects over Python interface
- And process them locally  and send it back to Python interface to reload config ?

So, depending on your circumstances, you can workout something with the following

Jython

[Pickle](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/pickle.html) (if you have no restriction on startup config file format or can afford to do conversion)

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pyro4

Also you can get some ideas from here:
[Sharing a complex object between Python processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671666/sharing-a-complex-object-between-python-processes)

Answer (score 1):

You should ask your python application to open a [XML-RPC socket](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html) which clients can connect on. This could let an outside application to execute an endpoint, which would manipulate your python object values in someway. [There are several good choices for Java XML-RPC libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582375/which-java-xml-rpc-library-to-use), including the amazing [org.apache.xmlrpc](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/) library.